# Select si me funciona en local pero en servidor no

Tags: php, html, phpmyadmin

Tengo el siguiente problema, tengo una consulta que pide confirmación antes de eliminar dicho registro, en local todo me funciona de maravilla, pero una vez que lo subo a hosting, no me sale nada, he estado borrando $row y solo así me aparecen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en servidor me aparece así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentando varias maneras de cambiar el cotejamiento desde las propias tablas, poniendo el UTF-8 en el .php y nada, no se que hacer.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], He visto que has agregado Imágenes, es preferible que tus ejemplos sean en texto y facilites el uso del mismo, También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: estoy tratando de adivinar tu codigo pero mis habilidades no llegan hasta aya... puede ser que tu servidor de base de datos este apagado... o que se le aya cortado el internet... tienes alguna otra informacion ayude con el problema que presentas?